# Remove a js array from the Next js main bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, mainbundle

There is a very large hard-coded array in my Next js application and I'm importing it in a few other places to use. Because of that, it has been included in the Next js main bundle. Since it is a very large file, I would like to remove it from the main bundle. Even though for components we can use next/dynamic to do this, for an array I couldn't find any method to resolve this. Could anyone help me with this one, please?
Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

main bundle content:-
[image]

Comment: Can you create an API route with it and call it when needed?

Comment: @AnthonyMa yeah! since it's an array, I could return it through an API.

Comment: Awesome, I'd appreciate it if you mark my post as the answer.

Comment: You can also just dynamically import the array (or whatever data structure) with [dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an API route and call it when needed, that's the benefit of Next JS, very easy to do that.